# randomly move files from a folder to another folder?

Tags: matlab, file, random, move, training-data

I am trying to move my files and create a new folder to put those files there.
I have many .png files in my images folder in my MATLAB directory. I want to randomly choose 80% of them and move them to another folder called training folder in my matlab directory. Heres my code which is not working. it cant find the file to move :(

```
data_add = fullfile(cd,'images');
all_files = dir(data_add);
all_files = all_files(3:end);
num_files = numel(all_files);
image_order = randperm(num_files);
for k = 1:(image_order)*0.8  
     file_name = all_files(k).name;
     file_add = all_files(k).folder;
     file_to_move = fullfile('path_to_images\images',file_name);
     mkdir training
    movefile file_to_move training

end
```

Comment: you shouldn't have mkdir inside loop. What is file_add used for?

Comment: Yes, I totally forgot about that mkdir. I just wrote it for giving path to the file I want to move but then I decided to use fullfile() I should've commented that too :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple issues here:

1. Like Flynn comments, the call to `mkdir training` only needs to be made once, so you can place it before your loop.
2. You may be thinking about the variable `image_order` incorrectly when it comes to your for loop.

   The call `image_order = randperm(num_files);` produces an array of randomly ordered indices from 1:num_files, which is helpful.  However, the expression `(image_order)*0.8` is actually multiplying each of these indices times 0.8, such that they are no longer valid, integer indices (aside from a few, like 8 which would become 1).

   I think what you are attempting and wanting to do is this:

   ```
   mkdir('training');  
   for k = 1:num_files*0.8
      randK = image_order(k);
      file_name = all_files(randK).name;
      file_to_move = fullfile(data_add,file_name);

      movefile(file_to_move, 'training'); % using function style
    end
   ```

You may run into other issues next depending on where the folder training is located and where you are running your script from, but this should be closer to what you are to get, and at least locate the files for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this code and I got the Error "using movefile
No matching files were found". But the file_to_move has the address and file name. So I dont know how to copy those file to training folder?

Comment: Perhaps you used the path name I gave as an example?  I edited the post with the variable name of the path you used (`data_add`, I believe).

Comment: No I used the data address but still said cant find the file!!

Comment: My apologies, try using the functional syntax of movefile, otherwise I believe it treats `file_to_move` as the string `'file_to_move'` which does not exist.  I updated the post accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. yes using function syntax helped.

Comment: Excellent.  Does this answer your question then?

Comment: Great.  Can you mark the question as Solved?  It will help others know this solution works for you.

Comment: yes sure thanks again. but just one thing in movefile function second element should be inside ' '. But didnt let me edit that.

Comment: Gotcha.   Thanks for letting me know.  I'll change it there and in the mkdir call for consistency.